# Reverse puzzling. What game is this?

Tags: reverse-puzzling

I saw my friend working on making a computer game version of an old game (not traditionally a computer game) and his notepad has these strange series of numbers. What game is he working on?

```
(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
(7,8,9)
(10,11,12)
(13,14,15)
(16,17,18)
(19,20,21)
(22,23,24)
(1,10,22)
(4,11,19)
(7,12,16)
(9,13,18)
(2,5,8)
(17,20,23)
(6,14,21)
(3,15,24)
```

And he says that is the complete set of sets (whatever *that* means!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This refers to

> Nine Men's Morris.

which uses this board

> ```
>     1-----------2-----------3
>     |           |           |
>     |   4-------5-------6   |
>     |   |       |       |   |
>     |   |   7---8---9   |   |
>     |   |   |       |   |   |
>     10--11--12      13--14--15
>     |   |   |       |   |   |
>     |   |   16--17--18  |   |
>     |   |       |       |   |
>     |   19------20------21  |
>     |           |           |
>     22----------23----------24
> ```

The listed sets are

> all the possible ways to get get three of your pieces in a row horizontally or vertically, which is a goal of the game.

Comment: That was quick!!! This was my first post :) good job